# java file relativize method performance

Tags: java, performance, relative-path, unc

i have a code that iterates over 100 000 files and get their relative path to some root directory and code is working but slow compared to another solution which is ugly (it's weird code but it's faster).

The original code is here:

```
File file, URI rootDirURI
for() {
   blabla = rootDirURI.relativize(file.toURI()).getPath()
}
```

vs

```
File file, URI rootDirURI
for() {
    String rootDirPath = rootDirURI.getPath().substring(1); // cut the first slash
    rootDirPath = rootDirPath.replaceAll("/", "\\\\"); // correct windows slashes
    String finalPath = file.getAbsolutePath().replace(rootDirPath, ""); // clear the root path: relativize
    blabla = finalPath.replace("\\", "/"); // slashes
}
```

Well the first for loop runs longer then 2 min and the second one run for less then 2 seconds... files are loaded over UNC path but this for loop is after Files.walkFileTree is executed. I have created symlink in my filesystem which has target to UNC path like \\192.168.1.x\public\something the first part loads everything in ArrayList and second part apply some operation (above code for loop) to files in that ArrayList.

does it means relativize is poor performance or toURI method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already noted by @Thomas, [Path.relativize()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#relativize(java.nio.file.Path)) definitely does much more than a simple string replacement.

But in this particular case, the bottleneck you have is probably `File.toURI()`, as it involves the filesystem access, when it tries to determine if your file is directory or not.

E.g. the following test code:

```
ArrayList<File> files = ...;
URI rootURI = base.toURI();
for(File ff : files) {
    String relative = rootURI.relativize(ff.toURI()).getPath();
}
```

took *68993 ms* to run on my machine, when applied to an array of 100000 files.

And according to [jvisualvm](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/jvisualvm.html), it spent most of this time inside the

`java.io.UnixFileSystem.getBooleanAttributes0()`

native method.

[image]

which can be traced back to `File.toURI() -> File.isDirectory()`

An equivalent code operating on an array of `URI` objects

```
ArrayList<URI> files = ...;
URI rootURI = base.toURI();
for(URI ff : files) {
    String relative = rootURI.relativize(ff).getPath();
}
```

took just  *3810* ms to complete, i.e. was almost **~20** times faster.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably both. If you have a look at the source code for both methods ([URI.relativize(URI)](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/net/URI.java#URI.relativize%28java.net.URI%29), [File.toURI()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/io/File.java#File.toURI%28%29)) you'll see a lot of checks, conversions and parsing going on. Since those methods need to work on a wide range of different inputs and still be somewhat fault-tolerant they need to do those things.

If you are confident that the file paths are already sanitized, normalized, correct etc. you can skip all those checks and conversions and thus be done with a few string operations.